# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/util/proxy/Proxy error while run my project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

**Hi i am new in spring hibernate i created one registration form with send OTP feature when my submit my form it show following exception error but i already add javassist jar in my lib folder**

HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/util/proxy/Proxy

type Exception report

message Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/util/proxy/Proxy

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/util/proxy/Proxy
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1276)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:958)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/util/proxy/Proxy
    org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxy(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:147)
    org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.getProxy(JavassistProxyFactory.java:75)
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.createProxy(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:771)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createProxy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4613)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxyIfNecessary(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:349)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:270)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1070)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:176)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.getReference(SessionImpl.java:2528)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:945)
    com.prakash.employee.dao.EmployeeDaoImpl.getEmployeeById(EmployeeDaoImpl.java:25)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and i fixed it by adding org.javassist version 3.21.0-GA in the pom file. This contains the Proxy class.

Answer (score 0):

Include missing Javaassist dependency in your project (add as library)
http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the library to the classpath?